# Import contacts from csv-file

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I'm new to Apps Script. Can a script be written to import contacts from a CSV file to Google Contacts? I have many such files, so I want to automatize the process.

I found in old records on this forum examples using the ContactsApp class, but it is not working anymore.

Comment: If you understand the scripting and the data structure much is possible. I believe contact has been replaced with People

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's important that you continue your development as a programmer beyond copy/paste in order to be able to better handle these situations. The Google Apps Script should have shown an error message and the IDE should show hints telling you that the the ContactApp service was deprecated.

Comment: From [Class ContactApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app) "Deprecated. Instead, use the People API advanced service"